# Removing references to child_added in Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm writing a Firebase web app (Javascript). If I write a reference to child_added like this:

```
dataRef.child('bids').child(auction).child(lotno).on('child_added', function(data){...}
```

"auction" and "lotno" are variables and will change as the app runs. I am writing the script to close each old reference (using OFF) whenever this happens, and then I open a new reference. My OFF looks like this:

```
dataRef.child('bids').child(auction).child(lotno).off('child_added');
```

First of all, am I doing this correctly? And second, is there a more universal way I can close child_added references, to avoid the possibility of one being left open accidentally?

Meaning, can I simply write Javascript that will close all child_added within 'bids'? Wondering if something like this is valid:

```
dataRef.child('bids').off('child_added');
```

Is there a wildcase that would cover all children? Would that close everything, or must each specific path through child elements be written out?

Comment: As far as know, listeners are registered/unregistered per reference, so you last example wouldn't work. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching-callbacks and https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html . But this is something you can simply try: write the code, have it execute and see if the events still fire.

Comment: Since I only have one listener in this path open at a time, what I decided to do was store the path values in separate variables. Then, if those are populated, later on I know exactly what path to turn "off". Even if the variables initially used to define the path have since changed. I think that should work fine.

Comment: Sounds good to me. If you can write it up in a bit of code, you might want to provide a so-called self-answer. Not only is that good for your reputation, but others might also benefit from your experience that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the path is built with two variables, and only one listener is open at any given time, I decided to solve this problem by simply storing the two values separately, in their own variables, such as:

```
    var storedPath1;
    var storedPath2;

    dataRef.child('bids').child(auction).child(lotno).on('child_added', function(data){
        if (storedPath1!=undefined && storedPath2!=undefined{
            dataRef.child('bids').child(storedPath1).child(storedPath2).off('child_added');
        }
        storedPath1=auction;
        storedPath2=lotno;
    }
```

If the listener was previously established, this will close it when opening the new one.